# How to check if slice of custom struct is sorted?

Tags: sorting, go, slice

We can check if a slice of strings is sorted with

```
var slice = []string { "a", "b }

sort.StringsAreSorted(slice)
```

But what about when you have struct and you want to know if a slice of that struct is sorted by a certain member?

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
  LastName string
}

var p = []Person{ {"John", "Smith" }, { "Ben", "Smith" } }

sort.StringsAreSorted(p???)
```

Comment: Then you have to do some programming. A simple foor loop is fone or use sort.IsSorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your type implements [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface), simply use the [`sort.IsSorted()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#IsSorted) function.

If not, you may use [`sort.SliceIsSorted()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SliceIsSorted), passing a `less()` function which decides / specifies the order(ing):

```
sortedByName := sort.SliceIsSorted(p, func(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].Name < p[j].Name
})
fmt.Println("Sorted by name:", sortedByName)

sortedByLastName := sort.SliceIsSorted(p, func(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].LastName < p[j].LastName
})
fmt.Println("Sorted by last name:", sortedByLastName)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aO8xDLPiuXs)):

```
Sorted by name: false
Sorted by last name: true
```

If you look into the implementation of these functions, they use a simple loop to iterate over the elements and tell if the ones being next to each other does not violate the ordering (`less()` function). You may just as easily use a for loop too.